# Bash for loop for each value of two (associative?) arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

Each line of /etc/trueuserdomains contains a username and its associated domain. I am trying to do `ln -s /home/$user /var/www/vhosts/$domain` for each line. I'm able to define two arrays with the required information. However, I am having trouble iterating through the array in the proper order.

```
#!/bin/bash

domain=(`cat /etc/trueuserdomains | cut -d: -f1`)
user=(`awk '{print $2}' /etc/trueuserdomains`)

for x in "${domain[@]}"
 do
  for y in "${user[@]}"; do
   ln -s /home/$y /var/www/vhosts/$x
  done
done
```

This repeats a single domain for each username, i.e.:

```
domain1.com user1
domain1.com user2
domain1.com user3
```

Close, but I need:

```
domain1.com user1
domain2.com user2
domain3.com user3
```

So basically loop through the domain array using the user array in the proper order. Any ideas? It sounds like associative arrays may help but unfortunately this server has only Bash 3, which does not support them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yet another one of those seemingly simple tasks that take far too much shell black magic. Is switching to Perl or Python an option for you?

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response. I also was just looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288206/is-it-possible-to-use-bash-to-access-more-than-one-array-in-a-for-loop and came up with this that works as well:

    domain=(`cat /etc/trueuserdomains | cut -d: -f1`)
    user=(`awk '{print $2}' /etc/trueuserdomains`)
    
    for x in "${!domain[@]}"
     do
      ln -s /home/"${user[$x]}" /var/www/vhosts/"${domain[$x]}"     
    done

Comment: See my reply: you don't need all those external commands for this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Am I missing something:

```
while IFS=:\  read -r d u; do
  echo ln -s /home/"$u" /var/www/vhosts/"$d"
done < /etc/trueuserdomains
```

Remove *echo* when happy.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is simplest to use an index:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#domain[*]}; i=i+1 ))
do
    ln -s "/home/${user[$i]}" "/var/www/vhosts/${domain[$i]}"
done
```